# Trying to fill a dropdown with options. Only a value is stored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am running this script:

```
    function insertformat(formats){
//Deletes the content of the dropdown if there was any
        document.getElementById('format').options.length = 50;
//fills the dropdown with an associative array
        for (var key in formats)
        var newOption = "<option value='"+key+"'>"+formats[key]+"</option>";
        $("#format").append(newOption);
    }
```

to fill the following select:

```
<select id="format"></select>
```

However only the last element of the array is stored. In the debug mode it seems that the dropdown is overwritten everytime the loop is finished, instead of adding a new element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the `appned` code is not `inside loop` so only `last value` is added to the dropdown. Change your loop like this.

```
for (var key in formats)
{    
 var newOption = "<option value='"+key+"'>"+formats[key]+"</option>";
 $("#format").append(newOption);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
function insertformat(formats){
       //Deletes the content of the dropdown if there was any
        document.getElementById('format').options.length = 50;
        //fills the dropdown with an associative array
        for (var key in formats){
        var newOption = "<option value='"+key+"'>"+formats[key]+"</option>";
        $("#format").append(newOption);
  }
}
```